# Common Login between site and iframed site

Tags: iframe, web-development-server, websecurity

I want to allow a login that happened on a parent site to automatically allow the iframed site to be logged in.

Here is the specific situation:

I have a site that is a simple login page.  After login the user has menu with a series of URLS (all with the same base domain but with different ports).

```
main.example.com   (main site)
main.example.com:14002  (iframe #1)
main.example.com:14003  (iframe #2)
...
```

The user selects one of the menu items and the url is loaded into the iframe.

The menu is driven off of a database table.

All the URLs will be loaded from the IIS but they all run on different ports so we have good control of being able to restart them and deploy new ones in the middle of the day.

What I am struggling with is finding a way to allow the login of the main site to allow the secure login of iframe sites.

In other words, how can the iframed site securely know the user id of the user that logged into the main site?

These are not arbitrary sites being iframed.  We are in control off all the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what we ended up doing:

The master site places a cookie with a token in it using this technique so it is visible to the module site:

```
document.cookie = "key=token;domain=mydomain.com"
```

Then the module.mydomain.com site does a web service call into master.mydomain.com website with the token to retrieve the logged in userid.

If there is no cookie or the token is expired the user is presented with a login screen in the iframe window.